# Electron-react Sequelize Sqlite - problem packaging

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, electron, sequelize.js

I'm building electron app with sequelize and sqlite3.
I have configured everything,
app works perfectly fine when i start it up with npm start
however when I npm run package it and I try to turn it on, I receive weird error that I have no idea how to tackle... :
[image]

I tried npm rebuild and ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild commands
Everything finishes succesfully but packaged app still doesnt want to work :/
What do I do wrong

Here are scripts :
[image]

I'm using Electron-boiler-plate for skeleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem.
First step was to import sqlite and add dialectModule to initialization of db in sequelize.

[image]

Second step was to manually add dependecy in release/app/package.json :
[image]

These Two steps made it work !!!